# Function to return different types based on input

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, auto

I want to write one function which would return me `String`, `Int`, `Float` based on some criteria. Using C11. Tried couple of stuff already mentioned, doesn't work with template/auto. If the function has only one return then its fine at the  moment. When I add another return say string, compilation error.  error: invalid conversion from `int` to `char*`

```
template<typename T>
T getProperty(int field,Json::Value root)
{
  for(int i =0;i < root["properties"].size(); i++)
  {
    if(root["properties"][i]["field"].asInt() == field)
    {
      if(strcmp(root["properties"][i]["type"].asString().c_str(),"int") == 0)
      {
      T convertedValue = (root["properties"][i]["currVal"].asInt());
        return  convertedValue;
      }


      if(strcmp(root["properties"][i]["type"].asString().c_str(),"string") == 0)
      {
      T convertedValue;
      sprintf(convertedValue,"%s",root["properties"][i]["currVal"].asString().c_str());
        return convertedValue;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `T` has to be known at compile-time, from the information available in the function's signature and its call site alone. And it can only be one type at a time.

Comment: Agree, call to this function is like this 
int l = getProperty<int>(1,root);
char name[50];
sprintf(name,"%s",getProperty<char>(2,root));

Comment: Oh yeah  as you said template is compile time stuff. This wouldn't work

Comment: I suppose you could concoct something with compile time "branching" through template meta-programming using SFINAE.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C++14, this simple example does work

```
template <typename T>
auto test(T a){
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    std::cout << test(a) << std::endl;
    double b = 2.0;
    std::cout << test(b) << std::endl;
    std::string s {"ss"};
    std::cout << test(s) << std::endl;
}
```

of course you will need to know the type you want to retrieve before the call, and that's probably not what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

You could use `boost::variant<string, float, int>` / `boost::any` as return type.

Please note that these classes are part of C++17 standard library.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by fully specialising your template. But you should probably split finding the correct `field` with returning the value.

You don't have to throw these exceptions, but if you don't, on the error path your program has undefined behaviour.

```
Json::Value getField(int field,Json::Value root)
{
    auto it = std::find_if(root["properties"].begin(), root["properties"].end(),
        [field](Json::Value item){ return item["field"].toInt() == field }); 
    if (it = root["properties"].end())
    { throw std::runtime_error("missing field"); }
    return *it;
}

// Primary template defined but not declared
template<typename T> T getProperty(int field,Json::Value root);

template<> int getProperty(int field,Json::Value root)
{
    Json::Value value = getField(field, root);
    if (value["type"].asString() == "int") 
    { throw std::runtime_error("not an int"); }
    return value["currVal"].asInt();
}

template<> std::string getProperty(int field,Json::Value root)
{
    Json::Value value = getField(field, root);
    if (value["type"].asString() == "string") 
    { throw std::runtime_error("not a string"); }
    return value["currVal"].asString();
}

// etc
```